# how to color code borders of states based on a column in usmap r

Tags: r, usmap

Hi i am trying highlight the states that are part of the program in a different color. This information is present in the data as "tag" column. Is it possible to do this in plot_usmap?

The following is currently the code i am using;

````
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "white", high = "red",name = "Percent") + 
  theme(legend.position = "right")```
````

Comment: Could you please share more code and your data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: also pls include more of your code, such as the steps preceding the `scale_fill_continuous()`